# Flutter ChangeNotifier, duplicate entries to list inside initState method

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Provider in my iniState(){...} of my list view page. If logged in, the user is redirected to this page automatically. The issue is that the initState(){...} is being called more than once and my list view has duplicate entries from firestore. Here is the code I have tried.
**It appears to be working on initial load, but if I hot restart it duplicates the items in it**

**MaterialApp**

```
home: FutureBuilder(
        future: Provider.of<AuthService>(context, listen: false).getUser(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<User> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            if (snapshot.error != null) {
              print("error");
              return Text(snapshot.error.toString());
            }
            return snapshot.hasData ? PropertyListPage() : WelcomePage();
          } else {
            return ProgressLoader(
              text: 'Loading, please wait...',
            );
          }
        }),
```

**List Screen initState(){...}**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    Provider.of<PropertyListViewModel>(context, listen: false)
        .fetchAllProperties();
  }
```

**list view model (Future) to get listings**

```
Future<void> fetchAllProperties() async {
    User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    await propertyCollection
        .where('emailAddress', isEqualTo: user.email)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) {
      snapshot.docs.asMap().forEach(
        (key, queryDocumentSnapshot) {
          properties.add(Property.fromSnapshot(queryDocumentSnapshot));
        },
      );
    });

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

This is where I set the ChangeNotifier

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();

  runApp(ChangeNotifierProvider<AuthService>(
    create: (context) => AuthService(),
    child: MyApp(),
  ));
}
```

Comment: Hotrestart does reload the app but keeps the state (your list).

Comment: Ok, so no need to worry as it won't be doing this in production environment, correct?

Comment: Even when I go to another screen and then transition back to the list view it keep existing items and reruns initState and adds duplicates.

Comment: Empty the list before you add new things to it